# How to enable Opscenter Settings and rebalance tab?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I am a newbie to the Opscenter and Cassandra.

After configuring cluster and nodes I found out that there is more load on two nodes: **I looked into action tab and found rebalance option but its grayed out and similar for the setting tab.**

Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rebalance works only when you have single-token cluster (https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/online_help/opscRebalanceCluster.html) - it won't work when you have vnodes enabled (num_tokens > 1 in cassandra.yaml). Depending on number of vnodes configured, you may have imbalance as well - with 8 you may have ~10% difference from average.

But this is true only for good data model - you may have some big partitions in your cluster, and until you change data model you can't do much. You can check for big partitions in the best practices part of the OpsCenter, or using the `nodetool tablestats`